# moving data of dt tag to single line

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3

i am trying to get the data in single line as shown in pic (option2)
https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=12yyvl18zmQUcwNrLtd8oOVKs_hL9t8mGeZxp6aLu-Q&usp=sharing

but i am getting like shown in below image .Any idea how to get this in single line like above .
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_-C_XOZHkVBZ1IweDhCRTlhcHdXbHBSMDNhMEVYRTNCdWFJ

This is my CSS code .

```
   dt:nth-child(4n+1), dt:nth-child(4n+1) + dd {
    background-color: silver;
    }
.dl-horizontal dt {
  max-width: 50%;
  text-overflow: inherit;
  white-space: normal;
  text-align: left;
  margin-left: 0px;
  padding:0px;
}

.dl-horizontal dd {
  margin-left: -1%;
  color: #6699FF;
  padding:0px;
}
```

And my HTML code.

```
<div class="col-sm-2 tabularData" data-placement="bottom" data-toggle="tooltip">
                            <dl class="dl-horizontal">
                                <dt>Status</dt>
                                <dd class="ng-binding">APPR</dd>
                                <dt>Trade</dt>
                                <dd class="ng-binding">H</dd>
                                <dt class="ng-binding">Booking CSR</dt>
                                <dd class="ng-binding">criticaltester</dd>
                                <dt>L/D Svc</dt>
                                <dd class="ng-binding">PIZ - CY</dd>

                            </dl>
                        </div>
```

Comment: your issue is not yet cleared, as there is no permission to access second link in your question. Still i feel you need to convert html block element to inline using following CSS

dt, dd {
    display:inline;
}

Comment: i have shared the access to second image .Please see